# ubuntu-16.10 unable to locate package

Tags: putty, ubuntu-16.10

I have recently setup Ubuntu 16.10 and am trying to install PuTTY but keep getting an 'E: Unable to locate package putty' error. I have run both 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get upgrade'. Both complete with success. I have verified that 'main', 'universe', 'restricted', and 'multiverse' are all enabled. But I continue to get the error when trying to install PuTTY. This is the command I'm using 'sudo apt install putty'.  Any thoughts on what might be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally determine that 16.10 was just too old to update properly. I have moved to 18.04 and successfully installed PuTTY.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when you follow the instructions on the PuTTY website.

Here is how to solve it for ubuntu:

instead of:

```
sudo apt-get install PuTTY
```

use:

```
sudo apt install putty
```

As expected the package is case sensitive but somehow even PuTTY haven't figured it out.